# Cannot see any nodes in neo4j graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm using the following command to populate data in neo4j database -

```
cat import1.txt | neo4j/bin/neo4j-shell -config neo4j/conf/neo4j.properties -path neo4j/data/graph.db
```

where `import1.txt` has the following content -

```
BEGIN

create (n {id:'pid_1', name:'Jo', type:'Person'});
create (n {id:'pid_2', name:'Ma', type:'Person'});
create (n {id:'pid_3', name:'Ph', type:'Person'});
create (n {id:'pid_4', name:'Lu', type:'Person'});
create (n {id:'pid_5', name:'Mary', type:'Person'});
create (n {id:'mid_1', name:'mov1', type:'Movie'});
create (n {id:'mid_2', name:'mov2', type:'Movie'});
create (n {id:'mid_3', name:'mov3', type:'Movie'});

start  n1=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_1'),         n2=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_2')   create (n1-[:friends]->n2);
start  n1=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_1'),         n2=node:node_auto_index(id='mid_1')   create (n1-[:watched]->n2);
start  n1=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_2'),         n2=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_1')   create (n1-[:friends]->n2);
start  n1=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_2'),         n2=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_3')   create (n1-[:friends]->n2);
start  n1=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_2'),         n2=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_5')   create (n1-[:friends]->n2);
start  n1=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_2'),         n2=node:node_auto_index(id='mid_3')   create (n1-[:watched]->n2);
start  n1=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_3'),         n2=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_2')   create (n1-[:friends]->n2);
start  n1=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_3'),         n2=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_4')   create (n1-[:friends]->n2);
start  n1=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_3'),         n2=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_5')   create (n1-[:friends]->n2);
start  n1=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_3'),         n2=node:node_auto_index(id='mid_1')   create (n1-[:watched]->n2);
start  n1=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_3'),         n2=node:node_auto_index(id='mid_2')   create (n1-[:watched]->n2);
start  n1=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_4'),         n2=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_3')   create (n1-[:friends]->n2);
start  n1=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_4'),         n2=node:node_auto_index(id='mid_2')   create (n1-[:watched]->n2);
start  n1=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_5'),         n2=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_2')   create (n1-[:friends]->n2);
start  n1=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_5'),         n2=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_3')   create (n1-[:friends]->n2);
start  n1=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_5'),         n2=node:node_auto_index(id='mid_3')   create (n1-[:watched]->n2);
start  n1=node:node_auto_index(id='pid_5'),         n2=node:node_auto_index(id='mid_2')   create (n1-[:watched]->n2);

COMMIT
```

Before importing data, I stop neo4j and after import I start it again. But in `http://localhost:7474/browser/` I don't see any node present. What can be the issue here?

When I run the same queries in console, it works i.e. nodes and relationships are being created.

Comment: That should work, and there is a `-file` argument you can use also. Do you get feedback like `Nodes created: 8`? Do you run the server with the same db dir? How do you query for the data in the browser?

Comment: Are you sure that the server running on localhost:7474 is pointed to neo4j/data/graph.db?

Comment: @FrobberOfBits thank you, that was the issue. I didn't see the path properly.